# Need help picking out a specific motherboard

Tags: motherboard, memory

I need to build a PC for my work, doesn't need an OS and can be a PC or server motherboard... The motherboard has to be able to work with all of the DDR4 options listed below (Not mixed at the same time of course). Also, would like to support up to 64GB per module if possible, but can settle for 32GB.

We would like the highest data rate possible but can settle for only going up to 2666. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Data Rate: 2133.33(PC4-17000), 2400(PC4-19200), 2666(PC4-21333), 2933(PC4-23466), and 3200(PC4-25600)

Voltage: 1.2v and 1.4v

Types: ECC, Non-ECC, Registered ECC, and Load Reduced

Comment: Does anything except RAM support matter? Intel or AMD? Which socket? How many PCIe slots? Budget? Size?

Comment: Just going to be used to test out RAM, everything else can be selected based on the MB

Answer (score 1):

It's virtually certain that no board meeting your requirements exists: you've got three mutually-contradictory requirements.

Registered memory is a technique for increasing the amount of RAM a board can support, at the cost of increased access latency.  Load-reduced memory is a different technique for doing the same thing.  Additionally, slowing down the memory clock can be done on any board to increase the memory capacity.

Any board where the manufacturer has added the extra circuitry needed to support registered or LR memory is one where they've already reached the limits from slowing down the memory clock.  I've found a scattering of SuperMicro server boards that support both registered memory and DDR4-2400, but nothing faster, and I haven't found anything that supports both registered and LR memory.

Comment: That is strange, I know that they are different technology but I have seen some HP and others support both HPE ProLiant DL580 Gen9 (2400 MT/s Memory) is an example of a server that supports both load reduced and registered memory. I know these different technologies cannot be run at the same time, and are rare, but they do exist